# Construct a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ such that each natural number can be expressed as a difference of two elements of that subset uniquely

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, contest-math

> Prove that there is a set $S\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ such that each natural number can be expressed as a difference of two elements of $S$ in exactly one way.

To be more precise, we want to show there exists a set $S\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ such that each natural number $n$ belongs to the set $P,$ where $P=\{a-b:a,b\in S, a-b>0\}.$ Moreover, if $n=a-b,$ with $a,b\in S,$ then there doesn't exist another pair of numbers $a',b'$ in $S$ with $n=a'-b'.$

A few observations can be made from the get-go. $S$ is necessarily infinite. If $S$ were finite, we could pick out the largest element of it, say $m$ and then we could say that all natural numbers greater than or equal to $m$ don't belong to $P.$ Also, if $S$ is a set that satisfies these conditions, then, $S+k=\{a+k:a\in S\}$ also works, where $k\in\mathbb{N}.$ So, if we show the existence of one set, we show the existence of infinitely many such sets.

My solution is as follows. We define a sequence of sets $A_1,A_2,A_3,\ldots,$ and to each of these sets, we assign two numbers: $f(n)$ and $g(n).$ $f(n)$ is simply $\max(A_n),$ and $g(n)$ is the least natural number not expressible as a difference of two elements of $A_n.$

Let
$$A_1=\{1,2\},$$
$$A_n=A_{n-1}\cup\{2f(n-1)+1,2f(n-1)+1+g(n-1)\},n≥2.$$

For example, $A_2=\{1,2,5,7\}.$ Here, $f(1)=2,$ and $g(1)=2$ as well. Similarly, $A_3=\{1,2,5,7,15,22\},$ as $f(2)=7,$ and $g(2)=7.$

Further, let $$A=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n.$$

Then, $A$ is the required set.

Is my solution correct? I feel like it should be since at each "step", we are adding two numbers such that an element that was previously missed is no longer missed and that the new differences created (other than this "missed difference") are all strictly larger than any existing differences.

Are there any other neat constructions we could use to solve this question?

Comment: My impulse would have been to just add in the least missing gap each time.  Thus getting $\{1,2,4,8, 13, 21,\cdots\}$ but I am not certain that this works.

Comment: @lulu, yes that was my first impulse too, and I did come up with that exact set the first time. But, we can't be assured it doesn't work since the new differences can overlap with the old differences. This doesn't happen for small examples (it may not happen at all), so it's tough to miss.

Comment: @lulu, is what I'm saying making sense? I don't think I'm getting my point across well.

Comment: Your solution looks fine. In fact, we can add $ \{h(n-1), h(n-1)+ g(n-1)\}$ as long as $ h(n-1) \geq 2f(n-1) + 1$.

Comment: @CalvinLin, yes, that makes sense. That preserves the property that the new differences are strictly larger than the old differences (except for the "missed difference").

Comment: The sequence I generate is, I believe, [A005282](https://oeis.org/A005282) and they claim a similar property for it, so maybe it works?   But I don't see a problem with your construction.  As you say, you eventually get all differences and each time you do, you are careful to only generate "new" differences which are greater than anything observed earlier.

Comment: @lulu I believe your sequence will be $\{ 1, 2, 4, 8, 13, 21, 31, 45, 60\}$, and then we get $29 = 31 - 2 = 60 - 31$. $\quad$ The OEIS enforces distinct differences, while yours is only "add least missing gap", so they are not the same.

Comment: @lulu, yes, Calvin points out the exact difficulty I was talking about.

Comment: @CalvinLin  Absolutely right.  Thanks!

Comment: We are indeed adding on missed differences, but nothing ensures that the added number doesn't create a difference that overlaps with an existing one.

Comment: OEIS sequence grows too quickly for us to really get the small differences. Eyeballing (so may not be correct), I don't see a difference of 20 or 70 in there, so it doesn't work for this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will be assuming throughout that $0\in \mathbb{N}$ and that $0$ is the only exception to the rule of being uniquely expressable.

Your idea of constructing a sequence of sets is not a bad idea. We can do this recursively, but before we construct the sets, we introduce a convenient notation:

For two subsets $A,B$ of $\mathbb{N}$ define

$$ A-B =\{y\in \mathbb{N} | \exists_{a\in A}\exists_{b\in B}[y= a-b]\} $$

And define the "closure under difference"

$$ A^D = A-A $$

Now we are ready to define the sequence recursively

$$ A_0= \{ 0\} $$

$$ A_{n+1} = \begin{cases}
A_n \cup \{10^{n+1}, 10^{n+1} +n+1 \} & \mbox{ if } n+1\notin A_n^D \\
A_n & \mbox{otherwise} 
\end{cases}
$$

This ensures that $$ [k] \subseteq A_k^D $$

Now we also need to show that for any particular $k\in \mathbb{N}$, that any element of $A_k^D$ can only be expressed in one way. We will of course do this by induction.

Clearly it is true for $A_0$ (vacuosly true since we don't even consider $0$ when checking our condition)

Now assuming it is true for some $A_n$, then either $A_{n+1}= A_{n}$ in which case the uniqueness condition is satisfied, so we can assume that

$$ A_{n+1} = A_n \cup \{10^{n+1}, 10^{n+1} +n+1 \} $$

However, the largest element in $A_n$ is $10^n + n$, so the smallest element that can be written as the difference between something in $\{10^{n+1}, 10^{n+1}+n+1\}$ and something in $A_n$ is

$$ 10^{n+1} - 10^{n} - n > 10^n+n$$

So we can conclude

$$ (A_{n+1}^D \setminus A_n^D)\cap A_n^D = \emptyset $$

And so every number in $A_{n+1}^D\setminus A_n^D$ (i.e. every number that got "added" to $A_n^D$) is obtained as the difference of something in $\{10^{n+1},10^{n+1}+n+1\}$ and something in $A_n$. If we suppose for the sake of contradiction that there is some such number that can be expressed in two different such ways, then we have some $a, b\in A_n$ such that

$$ 10^{n+1} - a = 10^{n+1} + n+ 1 - b $$

But rearranging this yields

$$ b-a = n+1 $$

Which is a contradiction since we are working under the assumption that $n+1\notin A_n^D$. Hence any element that gets added can be expressed in exactly one way, so the uniqueness condition holds for $A_{n+1}$.

Thus the uniqueness condition holds for every $A_n$, so it holds for

$$\bigcup_{i=0}^{m} A_i $$

To show that it holds for

$$A= \bigcup_{i=0}^{\infty} A_i $$

Is fairly straightforward, if it doesn't then there must be $a,b,c,d\in A$ such that $a-b= c-d$, but then just take the smallest $n$ such that $a,b,c,d\in A_n$, and obtain a contradiction.